# How to graph Binance API Orderbook with Pandas-matplotlib?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, graph, binance

the data comes in 3 columns after (orderbook = pd.DataFrame(orderbook_data):

```
   timestamp                bids                      asks
 UNIX timestamp      [bidprice, bidvolume]   [askprice, askvolume]
        list has 100 values of each. timestamp is the same
```

the problem is that I don't know how to access/index the values inside each row list [price, volume] of each column

I know that by running --->  bids = orderbook["bids"]

I get the list of 100 lists ---> [bidprice, bidvolume]

I'm looking to avoid doing a loop.... there has to be a way to just plot the data

I hope someone can undertand my problem. I just want to plot price on x and volume on y. The goal is to make it live

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you didn't present your input file, I prepared it on my own:

```
timestamp;bids
1579082401;[123.12, 300]
1579082461;[135.40, 220]
1579082736;[130.76, 20]
1579082801;[123.12, 180]
```

To read it I used:

```
orderbook = pd.read_csv('Input.csv', sep=';')
orderbook.timestamp = pd.to_datetime(orderbook.timestamp, unit='s')
```

Its content is:

```
             timestamp           bids
0  2020-01-15 10:00:01  [123.12, 300]
1  2020-01-15 10:01:13  [135.40, 220]
2  2020-01-15 10:05:36   [130.76, 20]
3  2020-01-15 10:06:41  [123.12, 180]
```

Now:

- *timestamp* has been converted to native *pandasonic* type of *datetime*,
- but *bids* is of *object* type (actually, a *string*).

and, as I suppose, this is the same when read from your input file.

And now the main task: The first step is to extract both numbers from *bids*,
convert them to *float* and *int* and save in respective columns:

```
orderbook = orderbook.join(orderbook.bids.str.extract(
    r'\[(?P<bidprice>\d+\.\d+), (?P<bidvolume>\d+)]'))
orderbook.bidprice = orderbook.bidprice.astype(float)
orderbook.bidvolume = orderbook.bidvolume.astype(int)
```

Now *orderbook* contains:

```
            timestamp           bids  bidprice  bidvolume
0 2020-01-15 10:00:01  [123.12, 300]    123.12        300
1 2020-01-15 10:01:01  [135.40, 220]    135.40        220
2 2020-01-15 10:05:36   [130.76, 20]    130.76         20
3 2020-01-15 10:06:41  [123.12, 180]    123.12        180
```

and you can generate e.g. a scatter plot, calling:

```
orderbook.plot.scatter('bidprice', 'bidvolume');
```

or other plotting function.

## Another possibility

Or maybe your *orderbook_data* is a **dictionary**? Something like:

```
orderbook_data = {
    'timestamp': [1579082401, 1579082461, 1579082736, 1579082801],
    'bids': [[123.12, 300], [135.40, 220], [130.76, 20], [123.12, 180]] }
```

In this case, when you create a DataFrame from it, the column types
are initially:

- *timestamp* - *int64*,
- *bids* - also *object*, but this time each cell contains a plain
  *pythonic* **list**.

Then you can also convert *timestamp* column to *datetime* just like
above.

But to split *bids* (a column of **lists**) into 2 separate columns,
you should run:

```
orderbook[['bidprice', 'bidvolume']] = pd.DataFrame(orderbook.bids.tolist())
```

Then you have 2 new columns with respective components of the
source column and you can create your graphics jus like above.

Comment: orderbook[['bidprice', 'bidvolume']] = pd.DataFrame(orderbook.bids.tolist())
         that line worked!
I can see it added two new columns with the labels 'bidprice' and 'bidvolume'.
And i can index them! so much win!!!